# Maximum Parallelisation Achieved (Data structures and Algorithms)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I saw this question in an interview experience on geeksforgeeks.

*You are given a list of data with the following attributes start time, Rest Api name/service name, end time. You need to find maximum parallelism that got achieved. Example – {{1, A, 4}, {2, B, 3}, {4, C, 10}, {4, D, 7}, {2, E, 4}}. The answer here is 4 because, at time t=4, there are 4 services running namely A, C, D, E respectively.*

The way I'd approach this would be to sort all the services on the starting time (if starting times are equal, then sort on the basis of the finishing time. Then for every process compare with other processes)
Would be great if someone could suggest an efficient method for solving this question.

Comment: What are the limits on time and other values, min/max?

Comment: @Surt, it's not specified.

Answer (score 0):

If max time is reasonable low

(totally untested)

```cpp
std::array<int, MaxTime+1> start;
std::array<int, MaxTime+1> end;
start.fill(0);
end.fill(0);
for(auto & service : services) {
  start[service.start]++;
  end[service.end]++;
}
int maxtime = -1;
int pos = 0;
int maxsum = 0;
std::inner_product(start.begin(),start.end(),end.begin(),0,
     [](int sum, int diff) { sum += diff; if (sum > maxsum) { maxtime = pos } ++pos; }, 
std::minus<int>())
```

Should be O(max(N, MaxTime))

If time is high or N is low then you might be better of with something like this

```cpp
sort(starttime)
sort(endtime)

par = 0
while(starttime)
  par++
  while (endtime < next(starttime))
    par--
  if (par > maxpar)
    maxpar = par
    time = starttime
```

O(NlgN)

Comment: Why are we using inner product here?

Comment: @Payal it takes two lists, two functions and is not a raw loop. It first subtract the values of the current time of start and end. Then sum them and check if it is a new maximum. Saves a call to std::max_element.